# Angular unit tests observable with subscribe method not firing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

How can I get this subscribe to fire in my unit tests.

```
.close.then((resolve: IModelInstance): void => {
    resolve.status$.subscribe((status: Status): void => {
      this._checkStatus(status);
    });
  });
```

the this._checkStatus(status) has some logic that checks value in order to fire the component's output.

Now so far in my unit tests, I have mocked the promise to return a resolve callback like so:

```
......as Spy).and.returnValue({
  close: new Promise((resolve: Function): void => {
    closeResolve = resolve;
  })
});
```

The data to pass to closeResolve is a follows:

```
        beforeEach(async(() => {

          closeResponseSubject = new Subject<Status>();

          closeResponse = {} as Partial<Instance> as Instance;

          closeResponse.status$ = closeResponseSubject.asObservable();

          closeResponseSubject.next(Status.CREATED);

          closeResolve(closeResponse);
        }));
```

On using this appraoch, in the component the tests do go into the "then" but not into the susbcribe. I've looked at different questions and answers here but so far no luck. I just quite don't understand why the test won't go into the subscribe. I don't know

Comment: You should unit test your `checkStatus` directly.

Comment: @Antoniossss how is that possible when the subscribe is failing to fire in my mocked test. checkStatus is being invoked as a result of a call back method in the subscribe, and the value of the callback is being passed to the checkStatus. How would you test checkStatus directly? P.s checkStatus is private method of the component's class

Comment: Make check status protected to make it testable. The whole idea is to write testable code that can be tested by simple tests.

Comment: @Antoniossss I see what you mean, the fact that I have spent so much time to unit test this approach, got fed up and in fact I have used a simpler approach, which I should've done so in the first place. Much easier to test

Comment: therefore I don't even need to test checkStatus, in this case i'm interested in the outcome of this method and that is the emit from the component. That I can easily spyOn() and use the spy in the expectation

Comment: when you *spent so much time to unit test this approach* you know that something is not right with the design. Writing (unit) tests should not take as much time as implementation of actual solution. This will come with experience - I have learned that the hard way as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Failed to figure out why the subscribe never fires with this appraoch,
so instead of doing this:

```
.close.then((resolve: IModelInstance): void => {
    resolve.status$.subscribe((status: Status): void => {
      this._checkStatus(status);
    });
  });
```

I used this implementation instead:

```
.close.then((resolve: IModelInstance): void => {
    this._checkStatus(resolve.status);
  });
```

Then in the unit test I have the following data mock - the promise mock stays the same:

```
closeResponse = {
  status: Status.CREATED
} as Partial<Instance> as Instance;
```

...............................................

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  closeResolve(closeResponse);
}));
```

By doing so I don't need to subscribe to status$ to get the value of the status model. I simply point to another property status which also has the value i'm interested.

Like @Antoniossss suggested: "The whole idea is to write testable code that can be tested by simple tests".